# SImple UPDATE statement freezing

Tags: psql

Trying to perform a simple UPDATE statement in psql:

```
username=> UPDATE table SET some_column = 'something' WHERE some_column = '';
```

returns:

```
username'>
```

And stays there with a flashing cursor.

I can return the details from the table:

```
username=> SELECT name, some_column FROM table WHERE some_column = '';
```

Something wrong with my syntax? Am I missing a step? Is there troubleshooting step to be taken?

Answer (score 0):

Went back in today and what I thought was the same query worked without error, however (!) when I scrolled up and looked at yesterday's queries, I had been using double quotes, which are treated differently than single ones by SQL.

So operator error, as often.